# How to set for loop javascript custom order number

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How to create number like this in JavaScript loop?

result '1' also result '1'

result '2' also result '2'

result '3' also result '3'

result '4' back to start result '1'

result '5' also result '2'

result '6' also result '3'

result '7' back to start result '1'

result '8' also result '2'

result '9' also result '3'

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You can use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) `%` and a `for` loop. But please, also share what you have tried and where you are getting stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let result = ""

for(let i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
for(let j = 1 ; j <= 3 ; j++){

   if(i === 10)
   {
     break;
   }
   
   
  if(i % 4 == 0)
  {
    result += ' result ' + i + ' back to start result ' + j +'\n';
  }else{
    result += ' result ' + i + ' also result ' + j +'\n';
  }
 
  if((i % 3) != 0)
  {
    i++;
  }
  
}
 if(i === 10)
  {
        break;
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The output is bit different the the OP's expected results, look `result 1 also result 1
result 2 also result 2
result 3 also result 3
result 4 back to start result 1
result 5 also result 2
result 6 also result 3
result 7 also result 1
result 8 back to start result 2
result 9 also result 3
result 10 also result 1
result 11 also result 2
result 12 back to start result 3`

Comment: Have updated...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
const loop = (from, to, limit) => {
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    let number = i % limit === 0 ? limit : i % limit;

    //do something with the number
    console.log(number);
  }
};
```

Then if you call it like this:

```
loop(1, 10, 3);
```

The logged result is 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1